# android: got error on trying work with spinner

Tags: android

i try to work with spinner on dialog

```
public class data extends Dialog {
.
.
.
String[] iType = { "AA","BB","CC" };
public Spinner TypeSelect;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.data);
     setTitle("My Heder");

     TypeSelect = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
     ArrayAdapter<String> TypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,iType);
        TypeSelect.setAdapter(TypeAdapter);
```

but i got error on this line:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> TypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,iType);
```

the error:

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(data, int, String[]) is undefined
```

what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dialog` isn't a sub-class of `Context` so you can't use `this` in the following...

```
ArrayAdapter<String> TypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,iType);
```

Try using `getContext()` instead of `this`.

Answer (score -1):

Spinners don't take string arrays try looking at the constructor on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) for more info.

Comment: but it work for me on regular Activity -  public class Statistic extends ListActivity

Comment: post the code for that please because I'm almost certain that they can't take strings and they only take references to strings.